# Xamarin.Forms how can I specify "Ambient" mode for an application using Xamarin.Android.Wear 2.0 libraries

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-wear-2.0

I have a Xamarin.Forms application using the Xamarin.Android.Wear 2.0 libraries for a simple one page application.  I'd like to utilize the Ambient mode feature to allow the application UI to stay somewhat visible when the

So, my question is can I do this in Xamarin.Forms and the Xamarin.Android.Wear 2.0 libraries?

As always, thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: @YorkShen I know how to do it in a native android project, but from a Xamarin.Forms project, how do I enable the app or page to go into ambient mode?